# Django: what is the difference between redirect to a view function and redirect to a url (from urls.py file)

Tags: django, redirect, view, django-urls

Which is better/standard practice?

```
  return redirect('index')
  return redirect('/users/new')
```

index is view function

/users/new is urlpatterns from urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using URLs directly is [discouraged by Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) (my bold):

> A common need when working on a Django project is the possibility to obtain URLs in their final forms either for embedding in generated content (views and assets URLs, URLs shown to the user, etc.) or for handling of the navigation flow on the server side (redirections, etc.)
>
> **It is strongly desirable to avoid hard-coding these URLs** (a laborious, non-scalable and error-prone strategy). Equally dangerous is devising ad-hoc mechanisms to generate URLs that are parallel to the design described by the URLconf, which can result in the production of URLs that become stale over time.

In other contexts you may wish to use [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) or [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url), or to add a [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method to your models.

Comment: I am still unclear on the usage of `reverse()` I had used the url-names directly in as: `redirect('url-name')` and seems to work fine. In fact, I think it really makes for a cleaner code. Are the url-names considered hard-coding still? Where does `reverse()` fit in?

Comment: I have also found that I can simply call another view function like this:
 `   return another_view_function(request)`
(being "creative" with my code) But I am not sure if it is legit good practice.

Comment: @theMobDog, `reverse()` builds the desired URL for you. You can use it however you want. That might be redirecting, or it might not. `reverse()` is an abstraction that lets you think about view functions, not URLs. [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) does something different: it returns an `HttpResponseRedirect` object. This isn't a string; it's something that can be returned from your view that will cause the user's _browser_ to load another page via [HTTP 301 or 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection).

Comment: URL names are an abstraction away from URL patterns, and as long as you name your URLs carefully they shouldn't change very often. It is probably better to use a URL name than a pattern directly. I wouldn't recommend `return another_view_function(request)`. If you want to redirect, use `redirect()`. That way your intention is clearer, and you're leveraging HTTP's built-in redirection.

Answer (score 1):

I think that index in your example is not a view function, but a url-name 
`url(r'^some/url/to/index', views.index_2, name='index')`

view functions can have `index_2` name and any url path, but you use "index" to redirect, for example `return redirect(reverse('index'))`.

As you can see, redirect only accept an url path, then reverse function receive a url name and return an url path, in the example reverse will return `"some/url/to/index"`